# Is it possible to make vscode sound an alarm when an unraised exception is caught while debugging, or at any breakpint?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm running some python tests and they take hours to run, I want vs code to make some kind of alarm so I know when a Breakpoint is reached that I wanna inspect or an uncaught exception is raised, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is followed by [issue 135908](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135908), and could be part of [VSCode 1.65 (Feb. 2022)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130565#issuecomment-1016216273)

> There are 3 different sounds since yesterday:
>
> - For lines with foldable areas,
> - with errors and
> - with breakpoints.
>
> I think you might have heard the sound for foldable areas.

See [PR 140044](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/140044) "Play a sound whenever a breakpoint is hit"

> - Use "`audioCues.enabled`": true to enable the feature.
> - Use "`audioCues.breakpointHit`": false to enable audio cues for breakpoints.

Comment: The setting ended up being named `audioCues`.

Comment: @Noumenon Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.